# Why the following code does not alert me all the child elements?

Tags: jquery

Based on the posiiotn of the shild elements, I want to get their IDS.However,the alert messages display me the child id and the parent id,then again a child id and the parent `id`.
`Child1`,`parent`,`child3`,`parent`,`child5`,`parent`,`child7`,`parent`..
Why is it skipping the child id to display me the parant id??

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JQuery</title>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.js">  </script>
<style type="text/css">
#parent{width:50%;margin:auto;border:#000 thick groove;overflow:hidden;}

#child1{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#00F;}

#child2{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;margin-left:30px}

#child3{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#00F;}

#child4{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;margin-left:30px}

#child5{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#00F;}

#child6{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;margin-left:30px}

#child7{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#00F;}

#child8{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;margin-left:30px}
</style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="parent">
<div id="child1" width="200px"></div>

<div id="child2"></div>

<div id="child3"></div>

<div id="child4"></div>

<div id="child5"></div>

<div id="child6"></div>

<div id="child7"></div>

<div id="child8"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var child = $('#parent').children().length;

    var child_id,child_width,child_X,child_Y;
    for (i = 0;i<child;i++){

            child_id = $('#parent').children().eq(i).attr('id');
            child_width = $('#parent').children().eq(i).width();
            child_X = $('#parent').children().eq(i).position().left;
            child_Y = $('#parent').children().eq(i).position().top;
            //alert(child_X);
            test(child_X,child_Y);
        }

function test(x,y){

    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    var $el = $(elem);
    alert($el.attr('id'));
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The above test is from FIrefox 4.I just tested in IE and it displayed parent for all alert expect thhe last one,child2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of `margin-left:30px`. This means that this element is not at the coordinates you expect by 30px. The margin space is not treated as part of an element. Instead of margin you can use border: `border-left: 30px solid #fff` or something.

Tested and it works at least for me :)

Comment: Ya it solved the problem in fiefox but prob persists in IE..Any way I can solve this?